# From javascript, how do I get access to the response page of a submit

Tags: javascript

From javascript I know how to:
    open an html page in another window,
    fill a form on the other window
    submit the form from the other window

What I don't know is, how do I then access the response page from the submit. Is it possible from javascript?

This is as far as I've gotten:

```
var nwin=open("http://myotherpage.html","");    
var frm_p = nwin.document.getElementById("frm_id");
var data_p = nwin.document.getElementById("input_data_id");
data_p.value = "my data";
frm_p.submit();
```

To make things clearer, myotherpage.html has a form:

```
<form id="frm_id" action="getResponse.html" method="post">
<input id="input_data_id" type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I want to get access to the getResponse.html page that comes back from the submit

Comment: you mean window.opener.document.form.submit? which page will be response page? child window?

Comment: the var nwin=open(..., opens another windows with the second page. Then the js fills the form and submits it (on the second page). The submitted form brings back a response page. That's the page I'd like to access in my js.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the form's `action='#'`, then put en event listener on `frm_p`. You should be able to access the form's elements in the listener, and then close the window after you get the value of all of them.

If clicking submit closes the open window, and you then no longer have access to the form's elements, I would change the submit button to type `button` and put the event listener on the button. Just make sure you close the window manually in the listener.

Comment: That is, assuming you are trying to process the form in the parent window.

Comment: As a side note, I would avoid opening the new window if you can. It can be unpredictable in browsers that have popup blockers and tabbed browsing. I would recommend creating an overlay to show your form, similar to the overlay for pictures in this plugin: [lightbox2](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#example)

Comment: Thanks, however, I can't change the form's action. It opens another html page. My javascript opens the second page in another window, fills the form, submits it, and it (the second page) has an action of a differet page, same window.